# Value of nLarge and it's item data

Tags: excel, function

I am working on excel sheet with multiple data point and its value.

The original excel data is as follow:

[image]

At first I want to use highest 3 value from array.
Therefore, I used **LARGE** function.
So Data appeared as follow in the sheet.

[image]

Now I want to use the value that results the corresponding nLarge value and insert under column **item**

The expected output is as follow:

[image]

The first data starts at cell A1 as shown below:
[image]

Which function do I have to use to achieve my purpose?
Can anyone suggest?
Thanks.
zep,

Comment: If I understand correctly, in B5 and copy down`=index($a$1:$j$1,match(c5,$a$2:$j$2,0))`

Comment: If you have duplicates, that won't work.

Comment: @SJR - that won't cover duplicates or triplicates. Might need aggregate with countif for the k parameter.

Comment: How can I maintain the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B5 and copy down:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($A$2:$J$2)/($A$2:$J$2=$C5),COUNTIF($C$5:$C5,$C5))
```